# writing a dict comprehension in loops

Tags: python

Can anyone help me make this dict comprehension into loop and such so I can understand it better. We have not done dict comprehension in school yet, and its all a bit confusing. Thanks for the help.

```
team2scores = {team: [input_dict.get(member) for member in members] for team, members in team_members.items()}
```

print(team2scores)

these are the dictionaries in case anyone need them:

```
team_members = {'TeamA': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Gertrude'], 'TeamB': ['Carol', 'Dave'], 'TeamC': ['Edith', 'Frank', 'Helen']}

input_dict = {'Alice': 1, 'Bob': 4, 'Carol': 5, 'Dave': 8, 'Edith': 6, 'Frank': 2, 'Gertrude': 9, 'Helen': 7}
```

Comment: You haven't told us what you wanted the output to be.  What should `team2scores` look like?  @chepner has made a reasonable guess, but it's just a guess.,

Comment: ahh sorry, must've forgot to do that. but I basically wanted to replace the names with their respective scores, like so: {'TeamA': [1, 4, 9], 'TeamB': [5, 8], 'TeamC': [6, 2, 7]}

Answer (score 2):

The conversion is fairly simple:

```
# team2scores = {team: [input_dict.get(member) for member in members] for team, members in team_members.items()}

team2scores = {}
for team, members in team_members.items():
    team2scores[team] = [input_dict.get(member) for member in members]
```

The generator becomes the start of the `for` loop, and the expression `k: v` becomes an assignment `team2scores[k] = v`.

Because you are making individual assignments to specific keys, you need to start with an empty dict that can serve as the target for the assignments.

Comment: Thank you @chepner :)